# export richtextbox image to png

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

We have an app that we want to capture screenshots using windows snipping tool, we are pasting the capture in a richtextbox. I want to export the image and save it a folder as png or jpeg. I have used the following code but it only captures the viewable screen.

```
Private Sub saveAsImage(ByVal box As RichTextBox, ByVal filename As String,  enter code here`ByVal format As Imaging.ImageFormat)
Dim rect As Rectangle = box.DisplayRectangle
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height,  ixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
Dim p As Point g.CopyFromScreen(box.PointToScreen(p), p, New Size rect.Width, rect.Height))
g.Dispose()
bmp.Save(filename, format)
bmp.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I can also to word or pdf, but it will only be images from the snipping tool no text.

Comment: If you are pasting an image/screen shot into a RTB, why not save that image rather than trying to rescue it from the text control?  You should also spend 30 secs exploring the tool bar to see how to format code as code.

Comment: it the way the user has been trained. They are used to creating email, fill in To, subject, snip a screen shot paste into body and send. We want to mimic that behavior in a winform. I think saving and then uploading a pic would turn them off.

Comment: No one said anything about saving and uploading.  The code in a button click could collect the image object from the clipboard *and* paste it into the RTB.  You'd then have the image for saving to disk, if/when needed.